# CodeVita challenge: forming the latest valid datetime in a year using some given digits

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, datetime

After [answering someone's Code Review question](/a/200439/9357), I decided to tackle [a sequel](https://www.programminggeek.in/2018/08/codevita-2018-round-1-question-date-time.html):

> Given an input consisting of 12 non-decreasing single digits separated by commas, form the latest valid date time in a non-leap year, in *MM/DD hh:mm* format.  Use each digit at most once.  If no date time can be constructed, the output should be 0.
>
> Example input: `0,0,1,2,2,2,3,5,9,9,9,9`
>   Example output: `12/30 22:59`

I was a bit dismayed to find that my previous answer, in Python, did not generalize very well to handle months of non-uniform lengths.  I also considered [@maxb's brute-force approach](/a/200466/9357) to be too inefficient.  (This challenge involves permutations of 8 digits chosen out of 12, or 19958400 tries.  Choosing 6 digits out of 9 for *hh:mm:ss* would only take 60480 tries.)

For an additional challenge, I decided to try using C++ instead of Python.  I used C++11, but advice based on any recent version would also be welcome.

Concerns:

- Is the solution readable enough?
- Is the design of the iterator idiomatic for C++?
- Any memory-management faux pas?  (The `this->pool.substr()` in `desc2iter::unused()` seems a bit wasteful.  I feel like doing `this->pool.c_str() + 2`.)

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/**
 * An iterator to form all possible two-digit numbers in a range from a pool of
 * digits, producing results in descending order.
 */
class desc2iter {
  public:
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * max:   The maximum allowable number to produce
     * min:   The minimum allowable number to produce
     * pool:  A pool of digits to use to form the numbers; each digit may be
     *        used at most once.
     */
    desc2iter(int max, int min, const std::string& pool);

    /**
     * If there is a next (smaller) number in the sequence, return true, and
     * set the result to the number.
     */
    bool next(std::string &result);

    /**
     * Return the characters in the pool that have not been used to produce
     * the most recent result.
     */
    std::string unused() const;

  private:
    int n;
    const int min;
    std::string pool;
};

desc2iter::desc2iter(int max, int min, const std::string& pool) :
    n(max),
    min(min),
    pool(pool) {
    assert(0 <= max && max <= 99);
    assert(0 <= min && min <= max);
}

bool desc2iter::next(std::string &result) {
    if (this->pool.length() < 2) return false;
    for (; this->n >= this->min; this->n--) {
        // Take the tens digit from the pool, if it exists in the pool
        std::string::size_type t = this->pool.find('0' + (this->n / 10));
        if (t == std::string::npos) {
            this->n -= this->n % 10;
            continue;
        }

        std::swap(this->pool[0], this->pool[t]);
        // Take the ones digit from the pool, if it exists and is unused
        std::string::size_type o = this->pool.find('0' + (this->n % 10), 1);
        if (o != std::string::npos) {
            std::swap(this->pool[1], this->pool[o]);
            this->n--;
            result = this->pool.substr(0, 2);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

std::string desc2iter::unused() const {
    return this->pool.length() >= 2 ? this->pool.substr(2) : "";
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Form the latest possible datetime, in a non-leap year, using the given digit
 * characters, in "MM/DD hh:mm" format.  Return an empty string if no valid
 * datetime can be formed.
 */
std::string max_datetime(const std::string& digits) {
    static const int month_lengths[] = {
        0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    };

    std::string MM, DD, hh, mm;
    for (desc2iter MM_it(12, 1, digits); MM_it.next(MM); ) {
        int month_len = month_lengths[std::stoi(MM)];
        for (desc2iter DD_it(month_len, 1, MM_it.unused()); DD_it.next(DD); ) {
            for (desc2iter hh_it(23, 0, DD_it.unused()); hh_it.next(hh); ) {
                for (desc2iter mm_it(59, 0, hh_it.unused()); mm_it.next(mm); ) {
                    return MM + '/' + DD + ' ' + hh + ':' + mm;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}

int main() {
    std::string input, answer;

    // Read input, keeping only digits
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    input.erase(
        std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](char c) {
            return !std::isdigit(c);
        }),
        input.end()
    );

    answer = max_datetime(input);
    std::cout << (answer.empty() ? "0" : answer) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Do you know *which year*? (it matters if it has a leap second)

Comment: The linked challenge says 2018. But leap seconds shouldn't matter, since the output omits seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is quite good, but I believe it can be made more readable and idiomatic.

### Iterator-based design

I find the question:

> Is the design of the iterator idiomatic for C++?

a bit ambiguous because, whereas iterators are a building block of C++ programming, I would say that your program doesn't use them. You write a `class` named after them, but that doesn't offer an iterator's interface. It's a pity, because your intuition is very correct, and your algorithm can be implemented very elegantly with iterators (and without any memory allocation). The basic block would have this signature:

```
Iterator parse_digit(int digit, Iterator first, Iterator last);
```

If successful, `parse_digit` find the character corresponding to digit, swap it with the last character of the `[first, last)` range and return `--last`. If not, it returns last.

You can then compose `parse_two_digits_number` over it, and then your date parser.

Without further ado, here's what it would look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename Iterator>
auto remove_digit(int digit, Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    auto it = std::find(first, last, '0'+digit);
    if (it != last) {
        std::iter_swap(it, std::prev(last));
        return std::prev(last);
    }
    else return last;
}

template <typename Iterator>
auto consume_two_digits_number(int n, Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    auto first_digit = remove_digit(n/10, first, last);
    if (first_digit != last) {
        auto second_digit = remove_digit(n%10, first, first_digit);
        if (second_digit != first_digit) return second_digit;
    }
    return last;
}

template <typename Iterator>    
std::string max_datetime(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    static constexpr std::array month_lengths = 
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};  
    for (int month = 12; month >= 1; --month) {
        auto month_it = consume_two_digits_number(month, first, last);
        if (month_it == last) continue;
        for (int day = month_lengths[month]; day >= 1; --day) {
            auto day_it = consume_two_digits_number(day, first, month_it);
            if (day_it == month_it) continue;
            for (int hour = 23; hour >= 0; --hour) {
                auto hour_it = consume_two_digits_number(hour, first, day_it);
                if (hour_it == day_it) continue;
                for (int min = 59; min >= 0; --min) {
                    auto min_it = consume_two_digits_number(min, first, hour_it);
                    if (hour_it == min_it) continue;
                    else {
                        std::stringstream ss;
                        ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << month << '/' << day << ' ' << hour << ':' << min;
                        return ss.str();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";                    
}
```

### Miscellaneous

You'll also notice I replaced your `month_lengths` array by a `std::array` (more idiomatic -that said, I should have specified the type and the size, since deduction guides are a C++17 feature), and used a `std::stringstream` to compose the return string: it has abysmal performance, but it doesn't matter here and it's more readable.

Comment: I think it's awesome that you can just manipulate a single pool of characters.

Comment: In my opinion, each field of the output should be zero-padded to two digits. But that's easy to fix.

Comment: @200_success: fixed